# Index of getElementsByClassName is undefined but not the whole object

Tags: javascript, getelementsbyclassname

I am trying to loop over elements with a specific class and attach an ID to them.

```
var items = document.getElementsByClassName("item");
for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
{
    items[i].id = "item_" + i;
}

console.log(items);
```

If I run that I get the error `Cannot set property 'id' of undefined`

However the `console.log(items)` returns me the correct collection of items:

```
HTMLCollection []
    0: div.item
    1: div.item
    length: 2
    __proto__: HTMLCollection
```

But as soon as I try to get the index `console.log(testimonials[0])` it is `undefined`.

HTML:

```
<div class="slider">
   <div class="item">
       Item 1
   </div>
</div>
<div class="slider">
   <div class="item">
       Item 2
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: please share your html

Comment: i tried your code in fiddle , it is working as expected
https://jsfiddle.net/gx0e26qw/

Comment: Make sure your DOM is rendered before running the JS

Comment: @Mango D: check my answer, it will work for you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue could be your script is running before the DOM is fully ready.

To solve the issue, you can place your code at the bottom of the *body*.

***OR:***

Try wrapping your code with [`DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded), this will ensure that your code will be executed once the DOM is fully ready.

```html
<script>
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    var items = document.getElementsByClassName("item");
    for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
    {
      items[i].id = "item_" + i;
    }

    console.log(items);
  });
</script>


<div class="slider">
   <div class="item">
       Item 1
   </div>
</div>
<div class="slider">
   <div class="item">
       Item 2
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That did the trick, thank you! But what is the reason that I am not able to access the index of `items` although, as described in my question, I can `console.log(items)` and get the correct output.

Answer (score 1):

With vanilla js always do DOM related operations after DOM is ready to use. And also before accessing/working with any DOM element check that it isn't nullable (not equal to null). With these practices you won't see any error with DOM elements because it is the safe way with manipulating with DOM elements. In regular loop always cache `array.length`. Avoid using anonymous function it is non-future proof and not debug-friendly way. Also write all js in separate js file.
HTML

```
<div class="slider">
   <div class="item">
       Item 1
   </div>
</div>
<div class="slider">
   <div class="item">
       Item 2
   </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", onDomReadyHandler);

function onDomReadyHandler(event) {
    var items = document.getElementsByClassName('item');
    var itemsLen = items.length;

    for(var i = 0; i < itemsLen; i++) {
      items[i].id = "item_" + i;
    }

    console.log(items);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using

> items[i].setAttribute("id", "item_" + i);

Fore more details you can visit documentation of

```
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_setattribute.asp
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_getattribute.asp
```

Fiddle for it:

```
https://jsfiddle.net/abdulrauf618/n14v58zs
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
        window.onload = function(e){ 
            var allItem = document.getElementsByClassName("item");
            for(var i = 0; i < allItem.length; i++)
            {
                document.getElementsByClassName("item")[i].setAttribute("id", "item_" + i);                
            }
        };
        </script>    
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="slider">
            <div class="item" id="">
                Item 1
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slider">
            <div class="item" id="">
                Item 2
            </div>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Hope it helps you.